# Likelihood - estimation on parameters

Tags: self-study

I make confusions in the using of **(1) Maximum Likelihood to find (approximately) the original signal knowing the data observed** and **(2)the using of Maximum Likelihood to find estimations of parameters of the PSF**.

Goal : Find (up to some point) the original signal :

I start from this general definition (in discretized) : $$y=H\,x+w\quad(1)$$ (with $w$ a white noise)

**Question:** How can I demonstrate this relation ? (it seems that we should start from a discrete convolution product, doesn't it ? Then, the correct expression would be rather : $y=H*x+w$ with $*$ the product covolution

Thanks

Comment: Is this homework? In that case change the question tags and add self-study. Also provide a better focus where you get stuck and most ideally focus on a single point. It is very difficult to follow your question.

Comment: It would be great if you could point to an example image. Is your data available online?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings ok, I have put Matlab script to understand better and the images that I have got.

Comment: You did not respond to my first comment yet (1: homework? 2: what focus?)

Comment: it is homework. Did you see the algorithm into my Matlab script ?

Comment: It is not easy to go trough that Matlab script but I see now a way to answer your question (if I understand it correctly).

Comment: How is finding $a$ a 'next step'? If you have the original signal then you also have $a$. Did you correctly describe the first step?

Comment: could you add the self-study tag to your question

Comment: -@Martijn Weterings I have just done it, hoping this will help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### When the image is a point source.

The convolution of the PSF with some original image becomes a simple function when the original image is a point source (ie it can be modelled with a delta function).

$$\begin{align}
d_{\text{after}}(r,c) & =  (d_{\text{before}}* PSF)(r,c) \tag{1a}\label{eq1a} \\
&= \int \int d_{\text{before}}(x,y) PSF(r-x,c-y) dx dy \tag{1b}\label{eq1} \\
& =  \int \int \delta(r_0-x,c_0-y) PSF(r-x,c-y) dx dy \tag{1c}\label{eq1c} \\
& =  PSF(r-r_0,c-c_0) \tag{1d}\label{eq1d}
\end{align} $$

see for more information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Translational_equivariance

So, in the case of a star/point-source, then your image is just the (single) PSF translated to the position of the coordinates of the star. **You can forget about the convolution (in the sense of intergrals) from this point and just work with the equation:**

$$d(r,c) =  a \cdot PSF_{\alpha,\beta}(r-r_0,c-c_0) + b + \epsilon(r,c) \tag{2}\label{2}$$

Your deconvolution problem is like you have some observation $d(r,c)$ that is dependent on a star positioned at $r_0$, $c_0$, that gives a signal with amplitude $a$ and is spread out by some PSF that depends on $\alpha$, $\beta$, and where you have an additional (uniform?) background $b$ and white Gaussian noise $\epsilon(r,c)$ with variance $\sigma_\epsilon^2$.

#### When the other variables $\mathbf{r_0,c_0,\alpha,\beta}$ are known

When the other variables $\mathbf{r_0,c_0,\alpha,\beta}$ are known then the function $PSF_{\alpha,\beta}(r-r_0,c-c_0)$ is *fixed* for every pair $r,c$.

Then this becomes like a ordinary least squares model ([OLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares)). $$ y_{r,c} = b+ a 
   x_{r,c}  + \epsilon_{r,c} \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$ with $$\begin{array}{rcl} y_{r,c} &=& d(r,c) \\ x_{r,c} &=& PSF_{\alpha,\beta}(r-r_0,c-c_0) \\ \epsilon_{r,c} &=& \epsilon(r,c) 
    \end{array}$$

#### When the other variables are *not* known

When the other variables are *not* known then it becomes like a non-linear regression problem, and you could solve it by a grid search or by using some algorithm for solving non-linear least squares prolems (of which there are many).

---

### What is the deal with the matrix equation?

You seem to be looking for some equivalence between convolution $f*h$ and some matrix equation $f.h$. But you should forget about this convolution since we are dealing with the simpler equation (2) instead of (1a).

One thing that might resemble an equivalence might be the fact that a convolution is equivalent to a product in frequency space, and it is this fact that you might use when you de-convolving when you are *not* dealing with point sources (see for more information https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution but note that this is not what you are doing in your exercise, which is a simpler case).

You can see the expression that you are working with (which would become a sum of PSFs for multiple point sources) as a sum of PSF with a *fixed* number of parameters. So you can put it in a form where you only have a limited number of parameters to estimate.

On the other hand, in the case of the convolution where the source image is not a point source (not limited numbers) the source image will be defined by an infinite sum of PSF functions and the system is underdetermined. You can not solve it as a simple regression problem where you minimize the sum of squares of the error.

---

Answering/helping some of your many questions

#### 1

> (it seems that we should start from a discrete convolution product,
> doesn't it ? Then, the correct expression would be rather : $y=H∗x+w$
> with $∗$ the product convolution )

In your particular question the star is considered a *point source*. In this case you do not need to use a convolution (or you do a convolution, but it is with a delta function see [sifting or sampling property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation))

#### 2

> What is the link between H and the PSF used above (Moffat PSF) ?

In matrix form you have the function $d(r,c) =  a \cdot PSF_{\alpha,\beta}(r-r_0,c-c_0) + b + \epsilon(r,c)$ as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}d(1,1) \\ d(1,2) \\ d(1,3) \\ \vdots \\ d(20,20)  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & PSF_{\alpha,\beta}(1-r_0,1-c_0) \\ 1 & PSF_{\alpha,\beta}(1-r_0,2-c_0)  \\ 1 & PSF_{\alpha,\beta}(1-r_0,3-c_0)  \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & PSF_{\alpha,\beta}(20-r_0,20-c_0)  \end{bmatrix} \times  \begin{bmatrix}b \\ a \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}\epsilon(1,1) \\ \epsilon(1,2) \\ \epsilon(1,3) \\ \vdots \\ \epsilon(20,20)  \end{bmatrix}$$

So $H$ is this matrix in the above equation, and it contains the PSF as a column.

Note that the $PSF_{\alpha,\beta}(r-r_0,c-c_0)$ and the image $d(r,c)$, make sense as two-dimensional objects, But they give you 400=20x20 separate equations, of the form in equation (2). You are just putting all those equations in 400 rows, and the columns in those equations make your matrix equation.

#### 3

> I have taken a y matrix (2D array)  ...  I don't know if it is correct to do this.

In my interpretation y should be a vector. Like I wrote explicitly in the above equation. The vector will have 20 x 20 entries.

Note that the vector/matrix notation only makes sense when you are applying linear algebra. E.g. when you solve the OLS problem. When you estimate $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the non-linear problem, then it is of little use.

#### 4

> Difference between deducing original signal and deducing parameters of PSF (Point Spread Function)

In the context of this problem you are estimating the parameters $a$, $b$, $c_0$, $r_0$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$. The first four parameters describing the original signal, and the latter two are parameters describing the PSF.

The difference is that deducing the original signal may turn the non-linear regression problem (when one of $c_0$, $r_0$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$ are unknown) into a linear regression problem (when $c_0$, $r_0$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$ are known).

Comment: -@MartinWeterings . thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the first part of code is already doing a linear regression. In the second part, that makes problems, I want to estimate the vector $x^{ML}$ from output data $y$ with the following formula : $x^{\text{(ML)}} = (H^{T}\cdot W\cdot H)^{-1}\cdot H^{T}\cdot W \cdot y$ , this is my main issue

Comment: Your first part is not clear ("Find (up to some point) the original signal"). What are the conditions?  Do you 1 know the PDF (including the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$) and wish to deconvolve the image or 2 you know the input+output image and wish to find the PDF? If both are unknown then it becomes very tricky and you may possibly solve it if you know additional properties of the situation (but in practice this situation does not occur, e.g. you first point the telescope to a known image, like an isolated bright star, to learn $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then you point to a complicated object)

Comment: In the first part :1.1) I fix the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then I produce the figure 1 by adding a white noise and a background. 1.2) Then I estimate the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (which are different from the initial values since the noise I have added). I perform this estimation by linear regression (one with **"\"** operator and another with **polyfit**.

Comment: In the second part, I fix also $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and I want to find x_input from y_output of figure 1 by using the Maximum Likelihood method and I use this relation : $x^{\text{(ML)}} = (H^{T}\cdot W\cdot H)^{-1}\cdot H^{T}\cdot W \cdot y$ but results are bad on figure 2. $x^{\text{(ML)}}$ must be I think a 2D vector estimation of input signal (given output image that I have with figure 1) ? Do you understand the formula : $x^{\text{(ML)}} = (H^{T}\cdot W\cdot H)^{-1}\cdot H^{T}\cdot W \cdot y$ with $W$ the inverse of covariance matrix ? here is the core of my issue.

Comment: No I do not understand your $x^{ML}$. Is it a vector containing $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the two coefficients that you wish to estimate? I do not think that you can estimate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by linear regression.

Comment: -@Martijn Weterings I don't want to bore you but I put in **UPDATE2** the different subtilities that I haven't still well understood (I have 3 questions). If you could help me, this would be great (I have a practise experiment in few days). thanks

Comment: @youpilat13 the question starts to become very much more off-topic than it already was. It would be better when you clearly state your original question, because your interpretation is not clear (whether you are gonna have to do a convolution or some matrix formulation is unclear). In the case that you use a point source then the convolution just becomes the function itself$$\int_x \int_y f(x,y) \delta(a-x,b-y) dx dy=f(a,b)$$You can use the same 'trick' with multiple point sources (the result becomes a sum of functions). But when the object is spread out then you use the Fourier transform.

Comment: -@Martin Weterings . thanks, my main issue is to prove : $h*x=H.x\quad(3)$ with $x$ vector, $H$ linear operator (matrix) and h the PSF (Point Spread Function), could you help me to prove it ? what that makes things difficult is the discretization of convolution product $h*x$ and the equality with matricial product "H.x". Regards

Comment: @youpilat13 what kind of function is $x$? It is a point source (a single star)? Or in other words you will be doing a convolution with a delta function and the convolution $h * x$ becomes just a function $h(a,b)$ where you have to estimate the coefficients $a$ and $b$ (which are the location parameters of the star/delta function). You can do this with (non-linear) least squares method but not with ordinary linear regression.

Comment: @youpilat13 Please enclose the full question/task that you have in order to get better help. It seems like you are confusing something but we can not help you to get in the right way if we do not know what way your are supposed to go.

Comment: -@Martin Weterings. Fast answer ! $x$ is a vector, $H$ is the matrix above with ones, $h$ is the transfert function (general case with $\text{output}=h\star\text{input}$

Comment: $x$ is a vector of what? Is it the pixels in the image? Provide the full question. This is too vague.

Comment: yes, $x$ is supposed to be an input vector and $h$ is supposed to be the response of the system towards a dirac function (here we are in continuous case and what interests me is the discrete case, such I could write H.x = h*x)

Comment: You should take note that the solution with the ordinary least squares method, which allows to express it as a matrix equation, is an entirely different thing than regular de-convolution. You only use the matrix expression when most parameters are already known (such as position of the star and shape/coefficients of the PSF) and when you only try to estimate the parameters $a$ and $b$ for the intensity of the star and intensity of the background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85691/discussion-between-youpilat13-and-martijn-weterings).